# Deleting rows corresponding to particular string, but keep NA values

Tags: r, subset, na

I want to delete all the rows from a data frame when a row in a specific column corresponds to one string, but keep NAs:

- delete all the rows from my data frame when 1st Column of my data has string values named "string". But my 1st column also has missing values - **NA**s, so when I use `df <- df[df$Col1!="string",]`, all the rows corresponding to string and NA values get removed from data frame.
- I want to keep NA values.
- also desirable:replace all `NA`s with `""` so that when I do `is.na(df$Col1)`, it shows False.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a condition with `is.na` to return those elements that are `NA` as well with `|`

```
 subset(df, Col1 != 'string' | is.na(Col1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `NA`'s with `""` using :

```
df$Col1[is.na(df$Col1)] <- ''
```

So now your original code would work and `is.na(df$Col1)` would return `FALSE`.

```
df <- df[df$Col1!="string",]
```